# Random Access by Position of Key/Value Pairs in .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, dictionary

I am currently developing a program that uses C#'s Dictionary container (specifically, SortedDictionary).  This container works very well for my purposes except for one specific case because I want random access.  Specifically, I am generating a random position using a pseudorandom number generator and I need to be able to access that value in the SortedDictionary.  At the point that this happens, I do not have a key value.

I could potentially switch to a List which would solve this problem, but would create problems in the rest of the algorithm where SortedDictionary works quite well.  Any suggestions/solutions would be much appreciated.

I am currently developing Visual Studio 2005.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public TValue GetRandomElement<TKey, TValue>(SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
    {
        Random randGen = new Random();
        int randIndex = randGen.Next(dict.Values.Count);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (TValue value in dict.Values)
        {
            if (i++ == randIndex)
                return value;
        }

        // this shouldn't happen unless I have a bug above or you are accessing the dictionary from multiple threads
        return default(TValue);
    }
```

Blindly enumerating the ValueCollection is not the most efficient thing in the world.  But it gets the job done.  If this is a frequent operation in your scenario, you should consider a hybrid data structure that has the performance characteristics needed for both dictionary lookup and random access.

Comment: The question didn't say anything about 2005 when I wrote my answer.  But ok -- I've edited code to only use C# 2.0 features.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a SortedList and it has a Values collection which you may access through an integer index.

Comment: Given the frequency of how often I need random access for this one part, I may switch to using a List.  Thank you for this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Linq could do this for you:

```
int n = GetRandomIndex();
object item = dictionary.ElementAt(n).Value;
```

Comment: +1, This is as good as it's going to get for SortedDictionary<T>.

Comment: He's using VS2005, so LINQ isn't an option.

Comment: @Colin: that restriction was added to the question after my answer. @arbiter: Whether it's expensive or not depends entirely on the amount of data and the frequency of performing the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Will pulling a random key work?

```
var randValue = myDictionary.Values.ToList()[myRandomInt];
```

**Edit:**

Seems the keys collection and values collection are both IEnumerables so you can't use [] operators. This is the best it gets it seems.

**Edit:**

Without Linq... Perhaps expensive, but you could copyto array and then pull a value at an index

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>[] dictCopy = new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>[myDictionary.Count];
myDictionary.CopyTo(dictCopy, 0);
var randValue = dictCopy[myRandomInt].Value;
```

Comment: That would work, but, as far as I can tell, AllKeys is not available to me.  Otherwise, this would be perfect.

Comment: Edited. The collection is called Keys.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide enough information to come up with a solution. How many elements, how often are you going to do this, do you have memory/speed constraints? BTree, SortedList, inserting special nodes in the SortedDictionary could all be useful